# set chrome permission for whole domain?

Tags: google-chrome, apache

I have a website running apache.

In my conf, I have this at the end:

```
<Directory /usr/local/django/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Files Top Secret"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user superuser_natch

</Directory>
```

And, as expected, I have to sign in to visit the site.

However, the served web page issues many followup requests to my site and those are all responding with 401 errors (if I try those urls myself, they work after re-entering my username/password).  Is there a way to tell chrome to apply the password credentials to a whole domain?

Comment: This is not a Chrome problem. This is an Apache problem. Browsers are basically dumb client applications and just do what is instructed. The repeated challenges are coming from the web server.

Comment: It may be important to check the file ownership and permissions within your web space. This may be important information to include in your question. Generally, Apache will use a username to run and files should be set to that user. Since I do not force authentication, I will defer and let someone with specific experience in this regard answer this question.